# Main Thread terminates before Task thread completion

Tags: c#, console, taskfactory

Hi i need your help guys,

i declared new Task inside my main method like this:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {    
       Task firstTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(()getPackage(packageId));
       Task secondTask=firstTask.ContinueWith((_=>UpdatePackage(myPackage)));       
   }
```

My problem is, the main thread terminates before my task completes its action.
 How should I wait Task to complete its action before terminating the main thread?

Comment: If you don't require **interaction** with this console app, then why use Tasks/Threads in the first place?  Just run your methods synchronously and let it exit when it's complete...

Answer (score 4):

Add the following code to make your main thread block until you hit enter in the command window.

```
Console.Readline();
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want a non-interactive solution, then you could just wait for all the tasks to complete.

```
Task.WaitAll(firstTask, secondTask);
```

Comment: thanks mike, but it requires me to hit enter every time, i want to put this console app to my server task scheduler and it will run every 1 hour, is there any ways other than adding  console.readline()?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an alternate paradigm for dealing with this.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MainAsync().Wait();
}
static async Task MainAsync()
{
    Task firstTask = new Task(()=>getPackage(packageId));
    firstTask.ContinueWith(()=>UpdatePackage(myPackage)));
    await firstTask.Run();
}
```

Be careful with mixing asynchronous and synchronous code like this, but, for your purposes, this should work fine (if this were winforms or WPF, you might have to worry about messaging to the UI thread, but that's not relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

Assign your task to a Thread and then in your main call the .Join() function of the created thread (after it has been started of course).  That way the application will wait until the task is over before ending.

This solution is more complexe than a Console.ReadLine but allows you to leave when the ask is over not before and not after.