# ChromeDriver times out instantly when using Task.Run() with await Task.WhenAll()

Tags: c#, async-await, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver, timeout

I'm trying to navigate to pages in parallel with ChromeDriver but as soon as I add "await" in front of the Task.WhenAll() call the driver times out within 1-2 seconds, not even close to the configured 120s timeout. What could be the reason for this and how can I fix it?

Using Task.WhenAll(..).Wait(..) seems to work fine. Why is that?

```
    var pages = new List<Task>();
    for (var i = 0; i < driverCount; i++)
    {
        var driver = _drivers[i];
        var url = urls[urlIndex++];
        Console.WriteLine($"{category.ToUpper()}: {urlIndex} of {urlCount} => {url}");

        pages.Add(Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Navigate() EXCEPTION:" + e);
                QuitAllChromeDrivers();
                throw;
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine($"Parsing: {driver.Url} - {driver.Title}");
            
            // parsing here ...
        }));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(pages);
```

```
    OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:52594/session/5c138e57c554ccfd59a45b243512c476/title timed out after 120 seconds.
     ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
     ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..
     ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (995): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
       at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.get_Title()
       at UnityAssetStoreScraper.Program.<>c__DisplayClass9_1.<ScrapeAssetContent>b__0() in C:\Users\Mee\RiderProjects\Scraper\Scraper\Program.Content.cs:line 74
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__277_0(Object obj)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you've written a console application?

```
public static async Task Main()
```

Consider this part of the error:

> The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a **thread exit** or
> an application request..

`await`ing will return execution to the main thread, which has no other work, and will thus end.

When you use `Task.WhenAll(pages).Wait()`, you force the main thread to continue running until all of your driver tasks have completed.

You can test this using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var captureI = i;
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine(captureI)));
        }
        Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait(); // vs await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}
```

Some solutions are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31576185/main-thread-terminates-before-task-thread-completion).